# Difference in ngApp behavior with app name and without app name

Tags: angularjs

I have following code which gives an out put as : add: 1 + 2 = 3

```
    <body ng-app>
      add: {{1}} + {{2}} =  {{ 1+2 }}
    </body>
```

The above code doesn't have an ng-app directive value but when I write same code with a directive value, behavior is different as following :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 add: {{1}} + {{2}} =  {{ 1+2 }}
</body>
```

Produces : `add: {{1}} + {{2}} = {{ 1+2 }}`

means Application doesn't recognize angular. Why is that?

Comment: I know it can be resolved by using angular.module('myApp',[]), but Why it is not happening at first place.

Comment: Since you have nothing that requires a *named* module, it works.  But once you name a module that you don't have, it breaks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when using myApp?

Comment: i get following Error :  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> means Application doesn't recognize angular. Why is that?

No, it means that Angular doesn't recognize the module name `myApp`.

This error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available

Indicates that Angular is searching for a module named `myApp`, but can't find one.  So, it breaks.

In the Angular.js [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/09ee82d84dcbea4a6e8d85903af82dcd087a78a7/src/Angular.js#L1414), you can see that a `module` (resolved by the name) is optional:

```
function angularInit(element, bootstrap) {
  var appElement,
      module,
      config = {};

  // The element `element` has priority over any other element
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';

    if (!appElement && element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute(name)) {
      appElement = element;
      module = element.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  forEach(ngAttrPrefixes, function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'app';
    var candidate;

    if (!appElement && (candidate = element.querySelector('[' + name.replace(':', '\\:') + ']'))) {
      appElement = candidate;
      module = candidate.getAttribute(name);
    }
  });
  if (appElement) {
    config.strictDi = getNgAttribute(appElement, "strict-di") !== null;
    bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);
  }
}
```

On the last line: `bootstrap(appElement, module ? [module] : [], config);`, it checks to see if `module` has a value and if not passes an empty array `[]`.  This is a valid *list* for `bootstrap` to handle.

Comment: Do you have any Idea how Angular Parses the directive with a name and without a name?

Comment: I would guess that Angular has an `ng-app` directive that takes in an isolated scope of `@name = ngApp` and then if there is no name, creates an *on-the-fly* (un-named) module.

Comment: is there any proper documentation regarding this because I searched in Angular official documentation but couldn't find.

Comment: You can look directly at the source?  I made an edit showing where in the source this is handled.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know that when you are not putting a name in ngApp directive. Angular will automatically looking for the module you are prefering right after the libary got loaded.

And about the error, it is possibly cause by the other of your script tags. After angular got loaded, it looking for your module but somehow your file not got loaded so you ended up with with some error.

**Solution will be:** Try to move your angular.js and your scripts to header. If it not working then move before footer. Also pay some attention on the order of them like:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**Or** using `angular.bootstrap()`

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```